# Weighted Average Calculation Based on Different Criteria

Tags: php, formula, average, weighted

I am working on a reverse auctioning system in PHP. My customers get bids from different vendors against their requested products/services. While displaying received bids to the logged in customer, I need to do a sorting based on weighted average against following criteria:

1. Price (40%) -> Lowest price is good.
2. Vendor Rating (20%) -> Rating = 1-5 (5 being best).
3. Delivery Options (10%) -> More delivery options offered the best.
4. Distance (10%) -> Lowest distance from customer location is the best.
5. Payment Methods (10%) -> More payment methods offered the best.

So far I have been able to create following formula:

```
$weightage = ($price*.40) + ($rating*.20) + ($delivery_options*.10) + ($distance*.10) + ($payment_methods*.10);
```

I need to show bids having highest weightage value on top. I am confused about the addition/subtraction of the weightage based on what is best for customer i.e if price is lower then this should be considered best for customer and should I add weightage or subtract weightage?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Well if for some of your criteria lower is better, but for others higher is, then you will have to at least reflect that by modifying the sign accordingly - because the end result is just one single number, so that number has to go up (or down, depending on which way you want to sort the results) for everything that is “better” for the customer.

Comment: But apart from that, I am not too sure if simply multiplying these values with a factor derived from the percentage makes much sense to begin with. Take the rating, multiplied with .2 that will add something between .2 and 1 to the final result. The price gets multiplied by .4, so the difference between two prices would only have to be 2.5, to completely “nullify” the effect that a rating of 5 has. Or differently put, the difference between rating 4 and 5 (only .2 of the final weight) would have the same effect, as a price difference between two items of only 0.5 would have.

Comment: Thanks a lot @04FS, that was really very helpful. I have posted answer below :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it sorted out. Here's what I did:

**Quote #1 (Best Quote)**

Price: 120

Rating: 5

Delivery Options: 2

Distance: 2000 km

Payment Methods: 5

Availability: 1

**Price Factor** = 1 - ( (Price - Min Price) / (Max Price - Min Price) ) = **1**

**Rating Factor** = ( (Rating - Min Rating) / (Max Rating - Min Rating) ) = **1**

**Delivery Options Factor** = ( (Delivery Options - Min Delivery Options) / (Max Delivery Options - Min Delivery Options) ) = **1**

**Distance Factor** = 1 - ( (Distance - Min Distance) / (Max Distance - Min Distance) ) = **1**

**Payment Methods Factor** = ( (Payment Methods - Min Payment Methods) / (Max Payment Methods - Min Payment Methods) ) = **1**

**Availability Factor** = ( (Availability - Min Availability) / (Max Availability - Min Availability) ) = **1**

**Quote #1 Weightage** = (**Price Factor** * 40%) + (**Rating Factor** * 20%) + (**Delivery Options Factor** * 10%) + (**Distance Factor** * 10%) + (**Payment Methods Factor** * 10%) + (**Availability Factor** * 10%) = **1**

Apply same formula to other quotes, you'll get weightage for each quote, and then you can sort quotes easily (Order by Quote Weightage Asc/Desc).